# How To Get to Every single HTML file in a URL

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So my code works but only for one url. (for example I used http://www.ancient-hebrew.org/m/dictionary/1000.html)

However I would like to apply every single html file URL to my code. Which can be found here (https://www.ancient-hebrew.org/m/dictionary/).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib


def getImage(_list):
    images = []
    # adds the url
    for image in _list:
        images.append(re.sub(
            r"..\/..\/", r"http://www.ancient-hebrew.org/", image['src']))
    return images


def getAudioFile(_list):
    audio = []
    # removes a tab character + adds the url
    for l in _list:
        audio.append("http://www.ancient-hebrew.org/m/dictionary/" +
                     l['href'].replace("\t", ''))
    return ''.join(audio)


def getHebrewWord(_list):
    hebrew = []
    for f in _list:
        hebrew.append(f.string.strip())
    return ''.join(hebrew)


url = 'http://www.ancient-hebrew.org/m/dictionary/1000.html'
file_name = str(re.search(r'(\d+).\w+$', url).group(1)) + ".txt"
raw_html = urllib.urlopen(url).readlines()
_list = []
_dict = {}
_ignore = {'audioURLs': '', 'pronuncation': [],
           'imageURLs': [], 'hebrewWord': ''}
for line in raw_html:
    number = 1
    html = BeautifulSoup(line, 'lxml')

    # Image Files URLs
    images = getImage(html.find_all('img', src=re.compile('.jpg$')))

    # Audio File URLs
    audioFile = getAudioFile(html.find_all('a', href=re.compile('.mp3$')))

    # Hebrew Words
    hebrewWords = getHebrewWord(html.find_all('font', face="arial", size="+1"))

    # Pronunciations
    pronunciation = [item.next_sibling.strip()
                     for item in html.select('img + font')]

    # Output: {'audioURLs': '', 'pronuncation': [], 'imageURLs': [], 'hebrewWord': ''}
    dictionary = {
        'audioURLs': audioFile,
        'pronuncation': pronunciation,
        'imageURLs': images,
        'hebrewWord': hebrewWords
    }
    if dictionary != _ignore:
        _list.append(dictionary)

with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
    for item in _list:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

So In the end I would like to write them to as many files. What would be an easy way to do this.

Comment: is `awk` script is option?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you made it somewhat unnecessarliy complicated (and - cardinal sin! - used regex on html D:). I tried to simplify parts of it - getting the links for the images and sounds and inserting them into lists. Note that, for various reasons, I changed some of the variable names you used - but it should be relatively easy to fit everything into your structure and extend it to get the word itself:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

url = 'http://www.ancient-hebrew.org/m/dictionary/1000.html'
raw_html = requests.get(url)

soup = bs(raw_html.content, 'lxml')

image_list = []
audio_list = []

images = soup.find_all ('img')
audios = soup.find_all ('a',href=True)

for image in images:
    if 'jpg' in image['src']:
        image_link = "http://www.ancient-hebrew.org/"+image['src'].replace('../../','')
        image_list.append(image_link)

for audio in audios:
    if 'mp3' in audio['href']:
        audio_link = "http://www.ancient-hebrew.org/m/dictionary/"+audio['href'].replace("\t", '')
        audio_list.append(link)
```

etc.